# Community-wiki of abbreviations

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I have a proposal for creating community wiki post for role-playing related abbreviations. The ones that made me scratch my head so far are SRD and OGL (now I know the meaning). All other like GM, NPC etc. may posted there.
Is it a good idea?

Comment: +1 SRD? OGL? Yeah.

Answer (score 3):

This experiment has already been initiated:

- [Glossary of Common RPG Terminology](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5475/glossary-of-common-rpg-terminology)
- [Glossary of Common Dungeons & Dragons Terminology](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5476/glossary-of-common-dungeons-dragons-terminology)

See also [Where can I learn the meanings of RPG terminology?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5469/where-can-i-learn-the-meanings-of-rpg-terminology) for links to existing glossaries.

Answer (score 0):

I think this seems like a good idea in principle, but maybe not in practice. The two main problems I see are:

(i) The answers will end up in whatever order people happen to think of them, whereas alphabetical would be a lot more useful. And there will be a lot of them.

(ii) The scope seems difficult to define. How obscure does an abbreviation have to get before it's not worth including? Community voting is not necessarily reliable on this point, unless we only want abbreviations used by the most commonly played games.

If someone can suggest an approach that avoids or mitigates these two problems, then I can see it being a useful resource. But (i) in particular seems problematic to me.

Edit: OK, (i) is not a big problem, because CW posts get edited by all and sundry until they are "right". So we don't have one answer per abbreviation.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397 for an example of a community maintained list of the badge descriptions

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I thought of too. I have the following idea: the main information will be in the question. People may suggest what abbreviations they think should be explained. Then moderators may sometimes add abbreviations to the question, if they decide they are worth of.

Comment: @yhw42: yeah, that's definitely better, than my idea.

Comment: @yhw42: Oh right, it works by editing. I see! Thanks! Scope might still be a problem, but it's probably worth an experiment